# Validate and show all error on page and remove errors on condition meet

Tags: javascript, validation, aurelia

I want to show all errors messages which i apply on Aurelia Validation .For example if user click on Password input box then all related error message should be highlight /show and hide/remove errors step by step as user meet the required condition .I show you my model .

```
"newpassword":{
        "name": "newpassword",
        "value": "",
        "rules": [
          {
            "type": "isValidRegExp",
            "args": [/(?=.*[a-z])/],
           "msg" : "Password must contain at least 1 lowercase alphabetical character."
          },
          {
            "type": "isValidRegExp",
            "args": [/(?=.*[A-Z])/],
            "msg" : "Password must contain at least 1 uppercase alphabetical character."
          },
          {
            "type": "isValidRegExp",
            "args": [/(?=.*[0-9])/],
            "msg" : "Password must contain at least 1 numeric character."
          },
          {
            "type": "isValidRegExp",
            "args": [/(?=.[!@#\$%\^&])/],
           "msg" : "Password must contain at least 1 special character."
          },
```

If user comes in Password Field the  4 error messages as shown in model should be show to user

```
1- Password must contain at least 1 lowercase alphabetical character.
2- Password must contain at least 1 uppercase alphabetical character.
3- Password must contain at least 1 numeric character.
4- Password must contain at least 1 special character.
```

then if user fulfill the option 1 then option 1 error should be hide/remove and so on.

Currently 1 error message is showing at same time .